# fetch(' https://644d-148-74-126-152.ngrok-free.app/login' doesn't find the login endpoint

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm using ngrok and flask under windows 11 and IIS and using port 80. when using the url, the login html is loaded proving that the ngrok communicates with Flask. However, when the client tries to communicate with an endpoint: https://644d-148-74-126-152.ngrok-free.app/login and on the flask side: @app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST']) the client call fails.There's probably a simple solution to this problem! BTW the flask is listening on port 5000, when changing the 80 to 5000 - ngrok http 5000 using the 5000 url (it is different) the call calls the flask server at @app.route('/'). so, if trying to reach a different endpoint is not possible. Your help will greatly appreciated.

Tried to play with the calling string, url and such to no avail.

Comment: `the flask is listening on port 5000` ...and how does the request you've shown on port 443 get to port 5000? magicks? or have you configured IIS to do so?